# Trying to Encrypt/Decrypt using AES. Progress == null;

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

Edit.

I guess I had a problem with creating a correct input into the encrypt/decrypt methods: These lines of code do the trick:

```
        string encrypted = en.Encrypt(stringBuilder.ToString(), "username", "password");
        string decrypted = en.Decrypt(encrypted, "username", "password");

        mainWindow.ChangeTextBox = encrypted + Environment.NewLine + decrypted;
```

I am just playing around and trying to figure out how encryption/decryption by using AES works. I am referring to this [article](http://www.gutgames.com/post/AES-Encryption-in-C.aspx) (pretty much copy and paste :( Trying to learn).

There they give me complete encryption/decryption methods which I have tried to modify. I am trying to pass a list of entries created by ArrayList then binded with string builder. It seems like I am able to encrypt data but decryption causes error:

```
Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.
```

at line with code:

```
ByteCount = CryptoStream.Read(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length);
```

How can I implement this code to be useful with my program and work correctly?

Regards.

Comment: Can you edit your code down to the minimum needed to demonstrate the issue?  That is a lot of code.

Comment: Would it be possible to say what parameters (cleartext, ciphertext, pass, usrName) causes that exception?

Comment: @ordag: 'PlainTextBytes.Length' seems to be the problem.

Comment: @Inuyasha: I tried, but there's still much code left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked through the code in detail, but it seems that the order of the parameters on the calls to `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` doesn't match the definition of the methods.  In the calls to these methods you appear to have *username, password, plain/cyphertext*; whereas the methods have the signature *plain/cyphertext, password, username*.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this and I have changed it after I have posted the question. Having my methods parameters formatted correctly I am still getting the same error.

Comment: You are correct! I have misinterpreted your question! I have edited my OP with lines that were not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Am I right it's caused for an empty or null string as plaintext? ;-)
**`"lol1"` can not be decrypted as it's not a valid ciphertext length (padding!)** *not to say it wouldn't make any sense.*

Comment: Well, it still causes a problem if I remove the text and leave as empty string.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: If you remove what?